# jQuery plugin validate() : apply plugin to ajax injected form

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

My issue here is quite simple : i'm trying to use the jQuery validate plugin to a form that gets injected after certain user actions.

My problem mostly is that :

- I could use live support to bind the change event over inputs, like this

  ```
      $("#adresseLivraisonPro").live('change',function(e){
      $("#adresseLivraisonPro").validate({
  ```

  But this makes my form validated if and only if user changes inputs...

How would you surround that problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback function of the AJAX call to apply the validation to the form.

```
    $("myformarea").load("urlof form.php", function(){
            $("The Form").validate();
    });
```

So the validation is applied after the form is loaded.

Comment: My bad, I did this befor, but, in order to keep things clear, made an external function... that I declared after the ajax callback... silly me... Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

apply the validation when you inject the form

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do something like

```
... user action ...
... retrieve formhtml somehow ajax/stringconcat ...
$("#formcontainer").html(formhtml); //inject form
$("#formcontainer form").validate(); //wire validation to form
```